# Phpfox 4 theme associated block

Tags: phpfox

Thanks in advance on this one.  How can I add a new block through the theme(not app)  in phpfox 4.6, so that this block is available in the admin side for block selection/location assignment? What source code changes do i have to make in the theme and where exactly?  Thanks again in advance

Answer (score 0):

You can't add new block on a theme.

Comment: From there official developer documentation, the Phpfox guys say you can now add a block from the theme. https://docs.phpfox.com/display/FOX4DEVDOC/Creating+and+Overwriting+Blocks+or+Controllers I just haven't succeeded in doing it. Perhaps, there's someone who knows how to take it on from here and actually achieve it

Comment: It's just a static html block. You can't add a complex block with theme.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Anyway, what I want to achieve is to display a single menu area that has all the category menus of groups, pages, blogs, marketplace. Is there a way I can call and display these blocks from different apps somewhere in the main layout.html? Thank you in advance

Comment: I think the easiest way is you create an app, and your theme require this app. When you package this them, you add add this extra app.